# OSX 10.8 Corrupted User Account Using Launchctl

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, launchctl

I used the following command:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
```

in an attempt to disable notification center. I'm not sure that I got all of the commands right and appear to have corrupted the account that I executed it from - I get a grey screen when I try to login on that account. Fortunately I have another account on the machine with admin privileges so I can still use the machine. I would however like to restore the account to a working condition preferably without having to resort to a complete system restore from my time machine backup.

Is there a way of diagnosing the current status of this launchagent and returning it to its original state?

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly the same thing yesterday - using launchctl to disable Notification Center corrupted my dock, icon bar, though it left the account barely functional.  Restore from TM did not work; searching the affected home directory structure for diffs did not yield anything useful for restoring.

Removing and rebuilding the same user account (without deleting the user home directory) does appear to fix the issue:  C.f.

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57437548-263/how-to-rebuild-a-user-account-in-os-x/

Yes, still drastic, but if you read through the article it mentions that the corruption may be in /var/db, not in the user home directory.  From there, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore your user files but not system software, you can use Migration Assistant.

Connect the external hard drive with the Time Machine backup to your computer.
Open Migration Assistant from Macintosh HD /Applications/Utilities. Enter your administrative password if required.
Under the migration method choices, choose From a Time Machine backup or other disk.
Select the external hard drive containing the previous Time Machine backups (it may take some time to scan the disk.)
Choose which “User Accounts” you would like to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

`launchctl unload -w` modifies `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist`, and `sudo launchctl unload -w` modifies `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`. Others with the issue could try modifying those files or restoring them from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do the same thing and what I eventually had to do to fix it is start up in recovery mode, change to /Volumes/Macintosh HD/var/db/com.apple.launched/

and edit BOTH the overides.plist files (both the one with your uid and the general one) and change the services that needed to run to have keys equivalent to false (not disabled).

Note that when you do this you'll probably want to follow this advice on fixing your vim keymap since you won't have normal imputed loaded.

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems

Also you may want to use
:set term=builtin_ansi

from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fix_broken_arrow_key_navigation_in_insert_mode

OMG I've never wasted so much time short of physical part failure.